# Base of Continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, continuity

is there a method to determine one of the infinite bases of the vector space of continuous function over an interval [a,b] (a

If the question is not "well asked" : How two functions in this space are indipendent?

Answer (score 2):

First question, [Axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300494/is-axiom-of-choice-required-for-there-to-be-an-infinite-linearly-independent-set) is required, no explicit example is possible. Second question: like usual vectors:
$f$, $g$ are linearly independent when
$$\lambda f +\mu g=0\implies \lambda=0,\mu=0.$$

Comment: But saying when two vectors are independent is not enough to define linear independence.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, true, but the OP question was "How two functions in this space are indipendent?"