# A vector space is either finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional and cannot be both

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$ and let's define the properties $(f)$ and $(i)$ in the following way:

$f$) $\exists F \in V$ finite such that $\text{span}(A) = V$

$i$) $\exists I \in V$ infinite such that $I$ is lineary independent

If I now define a vector space to be finite-dimensional if it satisifes $(f)$ and infinite dimensional if it satifies $(i)$, I definitely need to make sure that every vector space is *either* finite-dimensional *or* infinite-dimensional and cannot be both.

So the question is how to prove that
$$
f \iff \overline{i}
$$
or equivalently that
$$
i \iff \overline{f}
$$

Comment: You need at least the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice), see [this question](/questions/300494).

Comment: @user10354138 Thx. So from what I understands from Asaf Karagila's answer to that question, you can prove (assuming the axiom of countable choice) that $\overline{f} \implies i$. And what about the converse?

Comment: If a finite set $F$ spans the space, you cannot find more than $\#F$ linearly independent vectors.  This is part of the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks for the reference: I did not know this result had a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if (f) fails, you can inductively construct a linearly independent sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$.

If $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ have been chosen, then by assumption their span is not equal to $V$, so you can choose an $x_n$ which is not in their span...

Conversely, suppose $f$ holds, so that there is a finite set, call it $F = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ which spans $V$.  If $I$ is an infinite set, you can find $n+1$ distinct elements $y_1, \dots, y_{n+1}$ in it.  By elementary linear algebra, they cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: thx actually this (as does the answer to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300494/is-axiom-of-choice-required-for-there-to-be-an-infinite-linearly-independent-set) shows that $\overline{f}$ implies something even stronger than $i$, namely the existence of a _countably_ infinite linearly independent set. Right?

Comment: Yes.  But assuming some fairly weak version of the axiom of choice (which is already used in this argument), then every infinite set has a countably infinite subset, so you automatically get your "stronger" conclusion anyway.  (And the proof of the latter is basically the same as what I wrote: given an infinite set, start picking elements one by one, and you will never run out...)

Comment: Ops you re right! What about the other direction, i.e. that $i$ implies $\overline{f}$?

Comment: @Tom: See edit.

Comment: Thank you Nate - now it s all clear